# Accessing a schema inside a schema using Express Router and MongoDG

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm trying to create a route where it takes in a parameter for a username and then displays that users information. Only thing is, the username is in the user schema from when the user signs up. The profile schema references the user schema. How do I use the username parameter in the findOne call to display the users profile data?

User schema:

```
const UserSchema = new Schema({
  username: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  date: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
  }
});

module.exports = User = mongoose.model("users", UserSchema);
```

Profile schema:

```
const ProfileSchema = new Schema({
  user: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "users"
  },
  name: {
    type: String
  },
  image: {
    type: String
  },
  bio: {
    type: String
  },
  location: {
    type: String
  },
  website: {
    type: String
  },
  social: {
    youtube: {
      type: String
    },
    facebook: {
      type: String
    },
    instagram: {
      type: String
    },
    twitter: {
      type: String
    }
  }
});

module.exports = User = mongoose.model("profile", ProfileSchema);
```

Route:

```
router.get("/user/:username", (req, res) => {
  const errors = {};

  Profile.findOne({ user: req.params.user.username })
    .populate("user", "username")
    .then(profile => {
      if (!profile) {
        errors.noprofile = "There is no profile for this user";
        return res.status(404).json(errors);
      }
      res.json(profile);
    })
    .catch(err => res.status(404).json(err));
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this :

```
router.get("/user/:username", async (req, res) => {
    const errors = {};
    try {
        const profile = await User.aggregate([
            { $match: { username: req.params.username } },
            { $lookup: { from: "profile", localField: "_id", foreignField: "user", as: "userProfile" } },
            { $project: { userProfile: { $arrayElemAt: ["$userProfile", 0] }, username: 1, _id:0 } }
        ]).exec();
        if (!profile.length) {
            errors.noprofile = "There is no profile for this user";
            return res.status(404).json(errors);
        }
        res.json(profile[0]);
    } catch (error) {
        console.log('Error in retrieving user from DB ::', error);
        return res.status(404);
    }
})
```

Comment: @ii a, Can you please let me know, why do you want to use .findOne(), Do you've multiple documents in users collection having same username ? Or multiple profile documents matching to one user document ?these are not ideal, but just wanted to know on intention of using findOne! Based on that if needed we can change the aggregate query. In first case if you need get first one add {$limit:1} stage after $match,This query would work for 1 user doc to 1 profile doc plus also gets first profile doc in many matched(if multiple).If you need all matched profile docs do this $project  : userProfile: 1

Comment: I am pretty new to MongoDB so I'm not sure what the best solution would be. The user schema is used when people signup so there is only unique usernames and emails. There is also only one profile for each user. I tried the code you provided and I get an error saying: TypeError: User.aggregate(...).toArray is not a function

Comment: @iia : Ok, Sorry by mistake I had my local test env setup is on native driver, with mongoose we need to use .exec(). As mongo native driver has .toArray() whereas mongoose doesn't, updated my answer, Can you try now !!

Comment: It only returned the username but not the profile. I'm looking at your code and it looks correct. I just can't figure out where the issue is at

Comment: The user doc looks like: 
`{
    "id": "5d61de6f5c43e13c14482c23",
    "username": "testtest",
    "email": "testtest@test.com"
}`

Comment: profile: 
`{
    "social": {
        "youtube": "https://www.youtube.com",
        "facebook": "facebook.com",
        "twitter": "twitter.com"
    },
    "_id": "5d61dede5c43e13c14482c24",
    "user": "5d61de6f5c43e13c14482c23",
    "name": "testtest",
    "image": "https://images.pexels.com/photos/415829/pexels-photo-415829.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=750&w=1260",
    "bio": "blah blah blah blah",
    "location": "Phoenix, Arizona",
    "website": "google.com",
    "__v": 0
}`

Comment: @iia : Ok, In user document why do you've id instead of _id ? If you're mapping from id then in aggregation you need to change localField to 'id' instead of '_id'

Comment: I've tried to change the _id to id as well and it still returns the same so I'm not sure what it is

Comment: @iia : Ok not sure why, but I can suggest to run the same query in DB directly and check whether if its working or not, if it is then maybe you need to check in code on passed in values are being passed correctly or not, additionally what is the type of id in user collection and user field in profile collection, Do they match ?

Comment: The user field in profile is the same as the ID field in user. I was able to get the findOne example to work but it seems like aggregate is the better option so I'll keep hacking at it

Answer (score 0):

Try using aggregate, firstly you check-in user table for getting details of a specific username then fetch the profile details as below using lookup, if no profile found after unwind the document will not be fetched and you can check on aggregate result's length as aggregate always return an array in result :

```
  User.aggregate([
     {$match:{ username: req.params.user.username }},
     {$lookup:{from:"profile",localField:"_id",foreignField:"userId",as:"profileData"}},
     {$unwind:"$profileData"},
     {$project:{profileData:1,username:1}}
     {$limit:1}
    ])
    .then(profile => {
      if (!profile.length) {
        errors.noprofile = "There is no profile for this user";
        return res.status(404).json(errors);
      }
      res.json(profile[0]);
    })
```

Comment: Using aggregation is redundant in that case, 2 step search would be faster and cleaner.

Comment: @alpsavrum : .populate() is similar to $lookup - just the difference is it's provided by mongoose might have a bit more features, but $lookup is native !! when aggregation is used properly, performance hit might be very less considerable, not only aggregation any DB query has to have proper indexing and proper usage !! In real world you need to try to achieve things in one DB call effectively which avoids avoid multiple DB calls -  which has certain reasons like cost/latency several other factors. Please try to avoid making multiple calls if necessary..

Comment: When I try your code, I get the error "Cannot read property 'username' of undefined." I replaced username: req.params.user.username with username: req.params.username but it'll return "There is no profile for this user" even though I setup a profile for the user I'm trying to look up. Does the primary and foreign key need to be the same? If so, the _id from my profile is different then the id from the user

Comment: Add console to check the request params,then console the aggregate array and try to run in robomongo or studio3t.Also in above aggregate, in lookup we match userId saved in profile collection with _id in users collection,are they same?as i saw you gave ref to user collection in profile collection.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in 2 steps.

1. Look for users containing username in userSchema, get it's id.
2. Then in promise, use that id to, look for profileSchema contains.

   `router.get("/user/:username", (req, res) => {
       users.findOne({ username: req.params.username }).then(_user=>{
         profile.findOne({ user: _user._id }).populate('user').then(_profile => {
           res.json(_profile);
       })
     })
   });`

This code will look for username in userSchema and look for userSchema's id in profileSchema then returns profileSchema populated with user.